# No launch options in AppDelegate when opening the app from Manage option on Push Notification

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, apple-push-notifications, ios12

I am using the new iOS 12 push notifications management services and I have a problem. When the app is closed and I open it from "Configure in..." button:

[image]

the `launchOptions` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` are `nil`. I know the app later calls `openSettingsForNotification:`, but its too late in my case. Is there a away to know that the app is started from notification management in that method (`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`)?

Have Apple missed that, because when I tried to open the same options, but from:

> Settings -> #NAME_OF_THE_APP -> Notifications -> #NAME_OF_THE_APP
>   Notifications Settings

`launchOptions` is:

```
{
    UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey = "com.apple.Preferences";
}
```